# Can't CD into directory with 755 permissions?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, directory, docker

My directory has 755 permissions, but my user, `www-data` in this case, still can't `cd` into it. What's going on?

```
www-data@6265e61c98eb:/$ ls -ld root
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 15 08:22 root
www-data@6265e61c98eb:/$ cd root
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
```

This is inside of a Docker container, not sure if that's playing a role.

EDIT: Looks like it is a Docker bug fixed here https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/11799

Answer (score 0):

type

```
sudo su -
```

then give password
if your account is privileged to be able to have access to root then it should be successful, and afterwords type

```
cd /root
```

and you are in

Comment: Yes should have mentioned, as root I can CD in no problem, but I need www-data to be able to too.

Comment: see if you can do it by typing `sudo chown -R yourname:www-data /` and then type `sudo chmod -R g+s /`

Comment: Regardless, the directory seems to have a+rx permissions, what can possibly be keeping me from CD'ing into it?

Comment: did you try to `sudo su -` first?